# CIFeature class

Tags: macos, ios5

According to iOS Developer Library, CIFeature Class only has CIFeatureTypeFace or related to face recognition.

Is there any other feature types for shape? such as rectangle, circle, triangle, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not in the docs then either it doesn't exist (yet) or you can't use it.

So, (current) the only 'feature' type is Face, however, Apple typically create their API hierarchies to be able to support future expansion, as looks like the case here.

Updated for iOS9:
CIFeatureType now includes:
Face
Rectangle
QRCode
Text